# page size in spring boot to get total size

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination, jhipster

the default size of page is 20, I want to be able to get all elements from endpoint url.

to get 30 elements I set size like below :

```
http://localhost:8080/api/invoices?page=0&size=30
```

I don't want to change the default value of page size, I need to get total size from url but I didn't found how to set this.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `size` i.e. page size and `page` i.e. page number from URL using `@RequestParam`

```
@GetMapping
public List<Object> getInvoices(
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "page", defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
    @RequestParam(required = false, value = "size", defaultValue = "20") Integer size) {
  return <return response from here>
}
```

Here, default page size is 20 and page number is 0.

From UI side you just have to send values like this way,

`http://localhost:8080/api/invoices?page=0&size=30`

Note: I marked both the parameters as not required so that you can also use below URL to get all the invoices.

`http://localhost:8080/api/invoices`

So, change this as per your requirement.

For more information refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer! unfortunately `http://localhost:8080/api/invoices` returns only 20 invoices!

Comment: Ahh it's because the default value is 20. Either you can remove that default value and add check that will check if the value is not provided then return all and if it's provided then return limited records. OR you can create another endpoint to get all invoices just to avoid this complexity. I hope this answers all your questions. Please feel free to accept the answer.